# unordered_map C++

Tags: c++, stl

I am using unordered map like

```
unorderedmap.insert(make_pair(5, 6));
```

How could I get the iterator for the position of the key (value 5)? Do I need to use find() again or could I some how get it from the return value?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are using [this `unordered_map`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/boost/unordered_map.html), the iterator is:

```
unorderedmap.insert(make_pair(5, 6)).first;
```

Comment: `.second` tells you if it was successful.

Answer (score 2):

First of all `unordered_map` is not a standard container. But if you are using a `unordered_map` provided by the compiler which provides an API similar to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb982322.aspx) then it returns a pair of `<iterator,bool>`. The `iterator` part of the pair which can be accesses using `.first` will give you the location where the element got inserted (if it was inserted succesfully, this can be tested using the bool `second`).

Comment: It is standard in C++0x, which is not yet official, but most new compilers are already starting to implement it.

Comment: @Gorpik, @DeadMG: since the question is tagged STL, maybe the questioner "should" be using `hash_map`. Still has the same `insert` function.

Answer (score 0):

This is taken from http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/insert/

So as stated before, use the pair::first to get the iterator.

> The first version returns a pair, with
>   its member pair::first set to an
>   iterator pointing to either the newly
>   inserted element or to the element
>   that already had its same value in the
>   map. The pair::second element in the
>   pair is set to true if a new element
>   was inserted or false if an element
>   with the same value existed.

Comment: ah, I assumed he meant map. I learned something new thanks. Now to see the diff between the too :)

Answer (score 0):

The `unordered_map` interface is similar to the `set` interface or the `map` interface in that the `insert` method returns a `std::pair<iterator,bool>`:

- the `bool` is true if the insertion took place, it did not take place if an element with a similar key already existed in the container
- the `iterator` points to the right element: either the already existing one or the newly inserted one depending on the case

Therefore, if you only wish to access the element, you can simply use:

```
map.insert(std::make_pair(key,value)).first
```

However do check that you do not need to know if the insert was successful or not, in general one care about it :)